# Regular expression for 9 numeric characters and optionally two hyphens

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to match 9 numeric characters and optionally 1 or 2 hyphens.
The position of hyphens does not matter. I was able to get the regex to have one hyphen :

```
^([0-9]{9}|(?=^[^-]+-[^-]+$)[0-9-]{10})$
```

How can this be modified to include another hyphen?

Comment: If you just want to ignore all hyphens (which seems a bit more likely since you don't care where in the string they are), you could just do a  `Replace("-", "")` before your regex. Then your regex can be very simple. Or if you know where they should be, you can do something like `^[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{2}-?[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: Would `12--3456789` be OK? How about `--123456789`?

Comment: That would be ok too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
^(?!([^-]*-){3,})(?=(\D*\d\D*){9}$)[\d-]+$
 ---------------  ----------------
         |              |->match only if there are 9 digits
         |
         |->don't match if there are 3 or more -
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses a lookahead and ensure it conforms to the rule that it is comprized of digits with 0-2 hyphens.

```
(?=^\d*-?\d*-?\d*$)^-*(\d-*){9}$
```

Comment: you are missing `^`,`$` at end..`-` could be at the beginning or end